# What is a "cusp" ("кусок") in relation to Guba's embedding theorem?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

I'm confused by the definition of a "cusp" as found in

> V.S. Guba, *Conditions for the embeddability of semigroups into groups*, Math. Notes **56** (1994), Nos. 1-2, 763-769 ([link](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02110736)).

In the words of Mark Sapir (from an answer that has meanwhile been removed from this thread), "cusp" is a «weird translation» into English of the Russian term "кусок" (piece) used by Guba in the [original version](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=mzm&paperid=2237&option_lang=eng) of his paper. However, this is not the (main) point here: The point is rather that I have seen the same definition repeated elsewhere (with the terms "$s$-piece" or "$S$-piece" used in place of Guba's "кусок"), but continue to find it "strange". Let me try and explain my problem with Guba's definition, before asking a question.

Suppose that $S = \langle X \mid R \rangle$ is a semigroup presentation, and denote by $\mathscr F(X)$ the free monoid over $X$ and by $\ast$ the operation of word concatenation in $\mathscr F(X)$. Following Guba, it seems that

- a *defining word* (relative to $S$) is, as usual, any word in the set $\bigcup_{(\mathfrak a, \mathfrak b) \in R} \{\mathfrak a, \mathfrak b\}$;
- a *cusp* (*кусок*) is a word $\mathfrak u \in \mathscr F(X)$ such that there exist
  $\mathfrak p, \mathfrak p^\prime, \mathfrak q, \mathfrak q^\prime \in \mathscr F(X)$, with $\mathfrak p \ne \mathfrak q$ or 
  $\mathfrak p^\prime \ne \mathfrak q^\prime$, such that $
  \mathfrak p \ast \mathfrak u \ast \mathfrak q$ and $\mathfrak p^\prime \ast \mathfrak u \ast \mathfrak q^\prime$ are defining words.

But this doesn't look very natural. For one thing, what would prevent us from taking $\mathfrak p = \mathfrak p^\prime$ and $\mathfrak q = \mathfrak q^\prime$? Maybe I'm misunderstanding something and what Guba really means is that

- a cusp (кусок) is a word $\mathfrak u \in \mathscr F(X)$ such that there exist
  $\mathfrak p, \mathfrak p^\prime, \mathfrak q, \mathfrak q^\prime \in \mathscr F(X)$, with $\mathfrak p \ne \mathfrak q$ or 
  $\mathfrak p^\prime \ne \mathfrak q^\prime$, such $
  (\mathfrak p \ast \mathfrak u \ast \mathfrak q, \mathfrak p^\prime \ast \mathfrak u \ast \mathfrak q^\prime) \in R$;

or maybe there is a typo in the paper. In fact, I checked the original version of Guba's article, and at least for what concerns the definition of a "cusp" ("кусок"), there hasn't been any typo introduced in the translation process. I've also tried to follow the proof of Theorem 1 in Guba's paper, but there are some details I'm still trying to demystify. On the other hand, it appears that Guba's notion of "cusp" ("кусок") is borrowed from E.V. Kashintsev's paper

> *Small cancellation conditions and embeddability of semigroups in groups*, Int. J. Alg. Comp. **2** (1992), No. 4, 433-441;

except that Kashintsev uses the term "$s$-piece" instead of "cusp" ("кусок") and lets an $s$-piece be a word $\mathfrak u \in \mathscr F(X)$ for which there exist
$\mathfrak p, \mathfrak p^\prime, \mathfrak q, \mathfrak q^\prime \in \mathscr F(X)$, with $\mathfrak p \ne \mathfrak p^\prime$ or 
$\mathfrak q \ne \mathfrak q^\prime$, such that $
\mathfrak p \ast \mathfrak u \ast \mathfrak q$ and $\mathfrak p^\prime \ast \mathfrak u \ast \mathfrak q^\prime$ are defining words (as remarked by Kashintsev, these two words need not be distinct). This is one reason making me think that there is a typo in Guba's definition. The following excerpt if from the English translation of Guba's paper:

> The classes $K_p^q$ were studied in [[1](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02110736)]. By definition, a semigroup $S$ belongs to the class $K_p^q$ if it can be specified by a corepresentation (1) that satisfies the small cancellation conditions $C_s(p)$ and $D(q)$.

Here, item [[1](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02110736)] in the bibliography of Guba's paper is Kashintsev's paper (the same one mentioned in the above) and a semigroup is of class $K_p^q$ if it is isomorphic to a semigroup presentation $S$ with finitely many generators such that (i) no defining word can be expressed as the concatenation of less than $p$ "cusps" and (ii) the left and the right graphs of $S$ (that is, some undirected multigraphs naturally associated with the presentation) have both girth $\ge q$. Then, Guba's embedding theorem (that is, Theorem 1 in Guba's paper) is the statement that every semigroup of class $K_3^2$ embeds into a group. So I would expect Guba's notion of "cusp" ("кусок") to coincide with Kashintsev's notion of "$s$-piece", and yet the two definitions are different (and probably non-equivalent). With all this in mind, I'd like to ask the following:

> **Question.** Can anyone familiar with these things clarify the situation or suggest a reference where Guba's embedding theorem or generalizations of it are discussed as part of a more systematic treatment of the subject (e.g., a chapter in a book concerned with the embedding of a semigroup into a group)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "For one thing, what would prevent us from taking p=p′ and q=q′?". The "piece" definition requires existence of a common subword "u" in 2 different defining words (or in the same def. word but then "u" should be contained at least twice in that word). This is what is written in the definition mentioned.

Comment: And yes, "cusp" is a very weird translation. A 'piece' is a standart term, it was used by E.V. Kashintsev in semigroup context in his paper in 1970. It was used even earlier for group representations.

Comment: @TT_ It's been a while, but I think it should be $\mathfrak p \ne \mathfrak p'$ or $\mathfrak q \ne \mathfrak q'$ rather than $\mathfrak p \ne \mathfrak q$ or $\mathfrak p' \ne \mathfrak q'$ (as explained in the OP).

Comment: @TT_ It seems to me that, by your interpretation of the text (nowhere in Guba's paper one can _explicitly_ read that $u$ should be a common subword of two different def (= defining) words or contained twice in the same def word), every cusp (as per Guba's paper) is an $s$-piece (as per Kashintsev's paper), but not the other way around: Let $X$ be the $3$-element set $\{a, b, c\}$ and assume the only def rel in $R$ is $(a \ast b \ast a, c \ast b \ast c)$. Then $b$ is an $s$-piece (with $p=q=a$ and $p'=q'=c$); but is not a cusp because $b$ appears only in def words of the form $z \ast b \ast z$.

Comment: I would not call that my interpretation, that's rather standart description what the "piece" is (sorry, I can't make myself call it cusp). And yes, you are right - there is a typo in Guba paper. Being accustomed to the "piece" definition, it's hard to notice it. 
Accordingly, both Guba and Kashintsev definitions are equivalent.

Comment: Also I think it's S-piece (related to presentation S) in Kashintsev paper. I don't have a copy of Kashintsev paper, but pretty sure he meant it as S-piece. I believe he used the word "piece" (in Russian of course) when I talked to him. Maybe in the paper he had to distinguish pieces of two different presentations, so used a prefix "S" for that?

Comment: @TT_ (i) I'm sticking to the term "cusp" only for the sake of discussion (you and others have fully convinced me that "cusp" was not a best choice in the translation from Russian). (ii) I have a copy of Kashintsev's paper _Small cancellation conditions and embeddability of semigroups in groups_ and "$s$-piece" (with a lowercase "s") is the term being used therein. (iii) I should have bracketed the word "interpretation" in scare quotes: I hope it's clearer from the latest version of my own answer below what I was really meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** I had an email exchange with Victor Guba. He has kindly confirmed that there is indeed a typo in (the Russian and English versions of) his paper: a "кусок" (as per his paper) and an "$s$-piece" (as per Kashintsev's paper) are meant to be one and the same thing.

The part below was written before hearing from Guba.

---

(A recent comment of user TT_ has reminded me of this question, which has also entered a private exchange with [Laura Cossu](https://sites.google.com/view/laura-cossu) these days. So I've thought to post an answer in the hope that it can also be useful to someone else or those more familiar than me with the subject can shed further light on the story.)

As far as I can tell, there are two possible *interpretations* of the facts described in the OP:

- It is *implicitly* understood in Guba's paper (*as suggested by* TT_ *in their comment under the OP*) that either the defining words $w = \mathfrak p \ast \mathfrak u \ast \mathfrak q$ and $w' = \mathfrak p' \ast \mathfrak u \ast \mathfrak q'$ are distinct, or $\mathfrak u$ occurs twice as a subword of $w$.
- There is a typo in Guba's paper (and the typo has unfortunately spread through the literature).

In the first case, a cusp (as per Guba's paper) is always an $s$-piece (as per Kashintsev's paper); and in both cases, an $s$-piece need not be a cusp. E.g., consider the monoid presentation $H := \langle X \mid R \rangle$, where $X$ is the $3$-element set $\{a, b, c\}$ and the only defining relation in $R$ is the pair $(a \ast b \ast a, c \ast b \ast c)$: The only $s$-pieces of $H$ are the empty $X$-word $\varepsilon_X$ and the generators $a$, $b$, and $c$; while, *in any case*, the only cusps are $\varepsilon_X$, $a$, and $c$ (in particular, $b$ is not a cusp because it only appears in defining words of the form $\mathfrak z \ast b \ast \mathfrak z$).

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment above, both interpretations are correct. 
Also I have to mention that piece is usually defined as non-empty subword, there is no much sense to consider empty pieces. It should be mentioned in the definition of course.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, I'm not sure if it was Martin Greendlinger who first used the word piece. Maybe not. For ref.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_cancellation_theory

Comment: Sorry for so many comments... If needed, I can check/translate for you the definition from Kashintsev paper from 1970 where the diagram method was first applied to semigroups. His advisor was M.Greendlinger, so it was natural for them to extend the method to semigroup presentations.

Comment: @TT_ Many thanks for your informative comments. I agree that there is no much sense to consider empty pieces, but this possibility is not (explicitly) ruled out by the definitions in the papers cited in the OP and that's the only reason why I haven't ruled it out either.