# Irreducibility in a category

Tags: ct.category-theory

What is the "minimal" categorical structure necessary to define the notion of a "prime" or "irreducible" object in a category that would correspond to the idea of irreducibility (up to "unit" objects and permutation) arising in such diverse places as modules, natural numbers, ideal theory etc.?

Comment: Please clarify what kind of "combination" you have in mind behind the word "irreducibility".  Also, given that "irreducible" and "prime" mean different things in a ring (and for $\mathbb N$ there is a *theorem* about unique reducibility to primes), which of these notions do you have in mind? There are entirely different categorical answers in the various cases.

Comment: Answering these questions is part of the job of the people in the subcommunity of factorization theory. Have you already checked the refs in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407471? The notions discussed over there are framed in the language of monoids; rephrasing them in the language of categories is mainly a technicality (Baeth & Smertnig have done it explicitly in [J. Algebra 441 (2015), 475-551], though only in the very special case of cancellative categories). By the way, the short answer to your question is "None"; if requested, I'll add in further details (as time permits).

Comment: I second Salvo's comment -at least in spirit, if not in shape-, but probably it would be useful if the OP -in order to narrow down their question to something that can be approached/answered- specified if they want to factor the *objects* of a category, rather than the *morphisms* of the category, rather than *both*.

Comment: @fosco Whoops! I hadn't paid attention to the word "object" in the OP and really had morphisms in mind when I wrote my previous comment: If the focus is on the objects, then the language of monoids could already be enough (though much depends on what exactly the OP has in mind). E.g., there is a natural way to turn the isomorphism classes of objects of, say, a category with finite products into a monoid and thence talk of irreducibles, atoms, primes, etc. (of course, a little care is necessary to avoid set-theoretical issues).