# Characterizing atomicity in a commutative domain

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, factorization

In Proposition 1.1 of [Math. Proc. Cambridge Phil. Soc. 64 (1968), No. 2, 251-264], P.M. Cohn famously claimed (without proof) that a commutative domain is atomic if and only if it satisfies the ascending chain condition on principal ideals (ACCP). Some years later, A. Grams [Math. Proc. Cambridge Phil. Soc. 75 (1974), No. 3, 321-329] showed (by way of a counterexample) that Cohn's statement is wrong: Every commutative domain satisfying the ACCP is atomic, but not the other way around.

Grams' construction is commonly acknowledged as the *first* counterexample to Cohn's claim; and until now (2022-08-14, 13:40 CET), I too have believed that this was indeed the case. However, it appears that Cohn himself had already realized his mistake and sketched a (somewhat easier) counterexample on p. 4, ll. 14-18 of [Amer. Math. Monthly 80 (Jan., 1973), No. 1, 1-18].

In any case, it is natural to wonder if Cohn's claim can be, in a way, fixed by providing a *sensible* characterization (say, of a somewhat ideal-theoretic flavour) of when a commutative domain (or, more generally, a cancellative commutative monoid) is atomic.

> **Q.** I was confirmed that the question is open and well known (at least in some circles), but haven't found any solid evidence in support of this. Do you happen to know of any papers, conference proceedings, etc. (the older, the better) where the question, although somewhat vague in its formulation, is explicitly stated?

Let me recall that a (multiplicatively written) monoid $H$ is *atomic* if every non-unit factors as a product of atoms (i.e., non-units that cannot be written as a product of two non-units); and it *satisfies the ACCP* if there does not exist any (infinite) sequence $x_1, x_2, \ldots$ in $H$ such that $Hx_i H \subsetneq Hx_{i+1} H$ for all $i \in \mathbb N^+$. Accordingly, a domain is atomic if so is the multiplicative monoid $R^\bullet$ of its non-zero elements; and satisfies the ACCP if so does $R^\bullet$.

**Edit 1.** In the last lines of p. 3 in A. Geroldinger and F. Halter-Koch's monograph *Non-Unique
Factorizations. Algebraic, Combinatorial and Analytic Theory*, the authors cite Grams' example and add that "Up to now, there is no satisfactory ideal-theoretic characterization of atomic domains." The book dates back to 2006, but the question is likely ten to thirty years older.

**Edit 2** (addressing a [comment by მამუკა ჯიბლაძე](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428351/characterizing-atomicity-in-a-commutative-domain?noredirect=1#comment1101800_428351))**.** Apart from Grams' and Cohn's counterexamples (to Cohn's statement), atomic commutative domains that do not satisfy the ACCP are constructed by A. Zaks in [J. Algebra 80 (1982), 223-231] (where the author considers certain quotients of a polynomial
ring in infinitely many variables and proves that they are atomic without the ACCP) and by M. Roitman in [J. Pure Appl. Algebra 87 (1993), 187-199] (where, in Example 5.1, the author famously shows the existence of an atomic commutative domain $R$ such that the univariate polynomial ring $R[X]$ is not atomic, incidentally producing an atomic commutative domain without the ACCP). More recently, further examples were provided by J. G. Boynton and J. Coykendall [J. Pure Appl. Algebra
223 (2019), 619-625] (where the authors use pullbacks of commutative rings to construct large families of atomic commutative domains without the ACCP) and F. Gotti and B. Li [https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.00170] (where, among other things, the authors construct what appears to be the first-ever example of an atomic commutative monoid ring that does not satisfy the ACCP).

It is definitely much easier to construct cancellative commutative monoids without the ACCP. For instance, S.T. Chapman et al. prove in Corollary 4.4 of [Amer. Math. Monthly 128 (2021), No. 4, 302-321] that, if $r$ is a non-zero rational number smaller than $1$ whose numerator is not $1$, then the additive monoid of the cyclic Puiseux semiring generated by $r$ (i.e., the submonoid of the additive group of the rational field generated by $1, r, r^2, \ldots$) is atomic but does not satisfy the ACCP.

**Edit 3.** Let me share the following excerpt from an exchange with Alberto Facchini (I'm doing so with his permission): It doesn't really answer my question, but seems worth mentioning.

> Let $R$ be a commutative domain. As remarked by Cohn himself, all the notions above are described by the partially ordered set $L_p(R)$ of all principal ideals of $R$. For instance, $R$ satisfies the ACCP if and only if $L_p(R)$ is a noetherian poset, and $R$ satisfies the DCCP if and only if $L_p(R)$ is artinian. It is easily seen that $R$ is atomic if and only if, for every $I \in L_p(R)$, the interval
> $$
> [I,R] :=\{\, J\in L_p(R) \colon I \subseteq J\subseteq R\,\}
> $$
> has a maximal finite chain. Here, a *maximal finite chain* of the interval $[I,R]$ is a finite chain $I = I_0 \subsetneq I_1 \subsetneq  \cdots \subsetneq I_n = R$ of $[I,R]$ that cannot be properly refined into any other finite chain of $[I,R]$. See [A. Facchini and M. Fassina, *Factorization of elements in noncommutative rings, II*, Comm. Algebra 46 (2018), No. 7, 2928-2946]." I don't know though if that counts as a satisfactory ideal-theoretic characterization."

Comment: Every cancellative finitely generated commutative monoid is atomic, right?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Yes, every cancellative f.g. commutative monoid is atomic. More generally, if a monoid $H$ is left (or right) duo and locally f.g. up to units (i.e., for each $x \in H$ the smallest divisor-closed submonoid of $H$ containing $x$ is generated by $H^\times A_x H^\times$ for some finite $A_x \subseteq H$, where $H^\times$ is the group of units), then it satisfies the ACC on principal two-sided ideals and hence is factorable, which, considering that left duo monoids are Dedekind-finite, means that every non-unit factors as a product of irreducibles (i.e., $\mid_H$-minimal [...]

Comment: [...] non-units, where $\mid_H$ is the divisibility preorder on $H$ (namely, the binary relation on $H$ defined by $x \mid_H y$ iff $y \in HxH$)). A cancellative commutative monoid is, on the other hand, acyclic (i.e., $x \ne uxv$ unless $u$ and $v$ are units) and duo; and in an acyclic monoid, every irred is an atom and vice versa. (In fact, the result on left duo l.f.g.u. monoids I've just mentioned is a rather special case of a much more general thm.) But why this question on cancellative f.g. commutative monoids? Maybe you want to have a look at https://mathoverflow.net/a/414728/16537

Comment: I just wanted to get a feeling of the kind of monoids which might provide counterexamples. That is, atomic cancellative commutative monoids which are "bad". Presumably they must be infinitely generated, right? Can they be, say, submonoids of integer points in some polyhedral cone of ${\mathbb R}^n$ for some finite $n$?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Yes, if an acyclic comm monoid doesn't satisfy the ACCP, then the quotient obtained by modding out the units can't be f.g.: This is a consequence of the results mentioned in my previous comments (note that a cancellative comm monoid is acyclic). As for examples of atomic cancellative comm monoids without the ACCP, see Edit 2 in the OP. And for your last question, are you asking whether every submonoid of $(\mathbb Z^n,+)$ has the ACCP (with $n\in\mathbb N$)? I'm not sure to understand the terminology: You start with a convex cone of $\mathbb R^n$, and then...?

Comment: Maybe I got it. We start with finitely many vectors $v_1, \ldots, v_k$ of $\mathbb R^n$ and look at the submonoids of $\{a_1 v_1 + \cdots + a_k v_k \colon a_1, \ldots, a_n \in \mathbb N\}$ under addition, right? I'll think about it, I don't know the answer off the top of my head.

Comment: I was rather thinking about monoids of all vectors $v$ with integer coordinates such that $\varphi_k(v)\geqslant0$ for a finite family $\varphi_k$ of linear forms on $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I don't know about the ACCP, but the submonoid of $(\mathbb R^2, +)$ consisting of all integer pairs $(x, y)$ s.t. $y \leq \alpha x$ for some fixed $\alpha \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ has an empty set of atoms and hence is not atomic (since it's obviously not a group): This is item B4 of Theorem 10 in G. Lettl's _Atoms of root-closed submonoids of $\mathbb Z^2$_ in [Semigroup Forum 105 (2022), 282-294] and shows how tricky these things can be.

Comment: Sorry I should add the restriction that it does not have nontrivial units (equivalently, there is an open halfspace containing all of its elements except zero). For example, atoms of the monoid if integer pairs $(x,y)$ with $y\leqslant\sqrt2x$ and $x,y\geqslant0$ are $(1,0)$, $(1,1)$, $(3,4)$, $(5,7)$, $(17,24)$, ...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Do you want integer pts with _non-negative_ coordinates? This isn't clear to me from your comments (in particular, "I was rather thinking about monoids of all vectors $v$ with integer coordinates s.t. $\varphi_k(v) \ge 0$ for a finite family $\varphi_k$ of linear forms on $\mathbb R^n$") and makes a huge difference: Given $n \in \mathbb N^+$, every submonoid of $(\mathbb N^n,+)$ is BF-atomic (i.e., each non-unit has an atomic factorization and they are all bounded in length); and BF-atomic monoids satisfy the ACCP. (Btw, the group of units in Lettl's example _is_ trivial.)

Comment: Non-negativity is achieved by adding a bunch of appropriate $\varphi_k$'s but is not necessary - it just must be entirely contained in a half-space. For example, $y\geqslant0$, $y\geqslant-\sqrt2x$ (atoms $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(-1,2)$, $(-2,3)$, $(-7,10)$, $(-12,7)$, ...)

Comment: Or one might try all $(x,y)$ with $y>0$ together with $(0,0)$ which  has atoms $(x,1)$ for $x=...-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,...$ (this actually requires infinitely many $\varphi_k$'s but who cares...)

Comment: But now I see that all my examples are BF-atomic. Are any atomic non-BF-atomic monoids embeddable in $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I'm a bit lost (and I don't know exactly which comment of yours I'm answering). What about $(\mathbb Z \times \mathbb N^+) \cup (\mathbb N \times \{0\})$? This is item B2 of Theorem 10 in the aforementioned paper by Lettl: The group of units is trivial and the monoid is entirely contained in the _closed_ upper half-place of $\mathbb R^2$ but not atomic.

Comment: Well your example fails to possess **an open** half-space containing everything except zero, right? I believe this condition (together with integrality) ensures atomicity

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Yes, I realized to have missed the word "open" after posting my last comment (just on time to add the word "closed"). Anyway, the answer to "Are there any atomic non-BF-atomic monoids embeddable in $\mathbb R^n$?" is yes (already in dimension 1): See the paragraph starting with "It is definitely much easier to construct [...]" in the OP. And the answer to "Is there a monoid of integer pts contained, _apart from the origin_, in the intersection of an open half-space and a polyhedral cone of $\mathbb R^n$ that is not atomic" is still yes (or am I missing something else?): [...]

Comment: [...] The submonoid $H$ of $(\mathbb R^2,+)$ considered by Lettl in item B4 of his Theorem 10 (i.e., fix an irrational $α \in \mathbb R$ and put $H := \{(x,y) \in \mathbb Z^2 \colon y \le \alpha x\}$) is contained, _apart from the origin_, in the open half-plane $\alpha x-y>0$. On the negative side, I don't know if there is any monoid of integer pts contained, _apart from the origin_, in the intersection of an open half-space and a polyhedral cone of $\mathbb R^n$ that is atomic but doesn't satisfy the ACCP. Why not ask the question in a new thread? The comments are getting too long.

Comment: Yes you are right, atomicity is not ensured by my condition. And yes, maybe it is worth asking separately whether it implies ACCP. It may - I now think that every principal ideal in such monoid might coincide with its intersection with a line (through origin) in $\mathbb R^n$, which sort of forces ACCP, no?

Comment: No my last statement is not right either, sorry. In fact presumably every principal ideal is a shift of the monoid itself...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I made a new thread out of your question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428578/

Comment: Great, thanks for doing this! I was thinking about it too. Then I became sort of stopped by this thought: maybe strengthen the condition on the cone $C$ like this: $C$ is contained in a halfspace, and moreover intersection of $C$ with the boundary hyperplane of that halfspace is $\{0\}$...

Comment: Also, I believe we do not know the answer to the new question even if $H$ is the monoid of *all* integer points of the cone, right?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Yes, the answer is unknown even in that case (AFAIK). Actually, I was thinking about the problem over lunch and got the impression that we have in fact a dichotomy: Either a submonoid of $(\mathbb Z^n,+)$ is not atomic, or it is BF-atomic (I updated the other 3d accordingly). Btw, there is something wrong about your comment https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428351/?noredirect=1#comment1102068_428351: The existence of an open half-space containing everyting but the identity is _not_ equivalent to the group of units being trivial (consider the closed half-plane $x \ge 0$).

Comment: By open half-space I everywhere meant the one whose boundary hyperplane passes through the origin. Surely the $x\geqslant0$ does not admit one, no? As for dichotomy - does not the example by Chapman et al. that you described provide a counterexample?

Comment: So, you also want the separating hyperplane to pass through the origin (this wasn't clear to me). As for Chapman et al.'s example: That's a submonoid of $(\mathbb Q_{\ge 0}, +)$, and I don't think it embeds into $(\mathbb Z^n, +)$ for any $n \in \mathbb N^+$.

Comment: Right. And, right :)